# Laravel count number of Male or Female from a relationship table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have models below:

```
UserProgram user_id, program_id.

User

Profile, user_id, gender

Program
```

and I have a `function gender` in my `UserProgram` model

```
public function gender()
{
  $gender = "N/A";
  $user = User::find($this->user_id);
  if (!empty($user)) {
    $profile = Profile::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
    if (!empty($profile)) {
        $gender = $profile->gender;
    }
  }
  return $gender;
}
```

Now I want to run a query that counts how many male or Female I have for a particular program.
I want to be able to do something like this.

```
$male_count = UserProgram::with(‘gender)->where([

  ['program_id',104],[‘gender’,’Male’]

])->count();
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Im using laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above won't work as Laravel will be expecting `gender()` to return a `Relation` not a `Model`.

Assuming that you have a `user` relationship in your `UserProgram` model and you have a `profile` relationship in your `user` model, you can use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$count = UserProgram::where('program_id', 104)
    ->whereHas('user.profile', function ($query) {
        $query->where('gender', 'Male');
    })
    ->count();
```

Comment: I think this should work, but I wonder if something like 
    $count = UserProgram::with('user', 'profile')->where('gender', 'Male')->count()
would work.

Comment: I tried this, but i am getting the error

compact(): Undefined variable: operator

Comment: @FloEspen If you're just getting the count, there wouldn't be any reason to load the other relationships. I'm not sure how this would give you the desired result.

Comment: @ADEWOLE https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26936

Answer (score 1):

if your query in run change to

```
$male_count = UserProgram::withCount('gender')->where([['program_id', 104], ['gender', 'Male']])->get();
```

Comment: `gender` doesn't return a relationship.